# mayavi import UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, import, mayavi

I get a UnicodeDecodeError when I try to import mlab from mayavi and run a script from spyder.

I'm running a windows 8 machine. when I searched for this problems I found that non-ASCII characters should not be in the path or filename, but this is not the case in my example file test.py, which for this minimal example is stored in c:\test\

```
from mayavi import mlab
```

I get the following output in the console (It doesn't matter if I use Python or IPython Console):

```
runfile('C:/test/test.py', wdir=r'C:/test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 66, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mayavi import mlab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 27, in <module>
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 25, in <module>
    from engine_manager import get_engine
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from mayavi.preferences.api import preference_manager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\preferences\api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from preference_manager import preference_manager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\preferences\preference_manager.py", line 128, in <module>
    preference_manager = PreferenceManager()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\preferences\preference_manager.py", line 81, in __init__
    self._load_preferences()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mayavi\preferences\preference_manager.py", line 101, in _load_preferences
    app_home = ETSConfig.get_application_home()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\etsconfig\etsconfig.py", line 132, in get_application_home
    self._get_application_dirname())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 84, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode**

Source of error:

*File "....\lib\site-packages\pyface\workbench\workbench.py", line 319, in _restore_window_layo*ut

```
memento = pickle.load(f)
```

I edited it as follow, and it is working now :)

```
memento = pickle.load(f,encoding='latin1')
```